# Custom Json Deserializer constructor argument is null

Tags: json

I am writing a custom deserializer and mapping it as `@JsonDeserialize(using=CustomDeserializer.class)`

In the code below, clazz is null. How do I resolve this?

```
public class CustomDeserializer<T> extends StdDeserializer<T>
{    
    public CustomDeserializer(Class<?> clazz)
    {
        super(clazz);
    }
}
```

Comment: What language are you using? This looks like Java, but unfortunately it could also be TypeScript.

Comment: I am using Java